# Is triggering event listeners using ".click()" synchronous?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have the following code (where there is a `<button id="7">` in my HTML):

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  document.getElementById(7).addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log('clicked');
  })
  console.log('before');
  document.getElementById(7).click();
  console.log('after')
}());
```

When this runs in the Firefox 41 console, I would have expected

> before
> after
> clicked

because the code would run synchronously, and then respond to the click event on the event queue once it had completed the script. Instead I get

> before
> clicked
> after

This suggests the event is being handled synchronously?

Comment: @JavierConde If it is "asynchronous" in the sense of "places an event on the event queue" then the event can only resolve once the current function stack has cleared. I guess it *could* do something that would satisfy the computer-science definition of "asynchronous" that isn't "place an event on the event queue", but I'm not familiar with any JavaScript spec or implementation that defines such behavior. (That is, all asynchronous JS implementations I know of use an event queue that only pops when the JS engine is idle.) Can you point out where such behavior might be defined or implemented?

Comment: @apsillers, you are right, I knew JS was single-threaded but thought it could have some kind of mechanism to trigger interruptions. It is not the case.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, the [`click` method](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#dom-click) does synchronously run the activation steps which includes immediately firing (creating and dispatching) the event. It is not put in the event loop queue.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be confined to using the click method. I get the same for hover events and mousedown events using `target.dispatchEvent(new Event("hover")` for example. I'm not sure how to generalize my question, but I generally thought events go on the event queue, but these user interaction events seem not to?

Comment: Yes, [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) is synchronous as well (in fact, it even has a return value depending on the effects of the listeners).

Comment: Are you suggesting that these same events would be handled asynchronously if they were the result of a user-browser interaction?

Comment: What does "asynchronously" mean for user interaction anyway? The event queue only ensures that events happen in sequence (and not somehow parallel). There is nothing that could happen "out-of-sync", like an ajax request.

Comment: I suppose I meant that if a user interaction event were to hypothetically trigger at the exact same moment as the call to .click() above, that it wouldn't interrupt the current execution. Seems like the answer is exactly: it wouldn't. Thanks so much for the help.