# Javascript event listener callback function should wait in callback queue

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, event-listener, callstack

This is my js code ,

```
function doSomething() { 

  const ele = document.getElementById('a');

  ele.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('clicked');
  });

  console.log('before');

  ele.click();

  console.log('after');
}
doSomething()
```

My understanding is -  if event listener is triggered, respective callback function will wait in callback queue, until call stacks gets empty and then only it gets executed

If this is correct, the output for this code should be in this order right - **before, after, clicked**

But actual output here is - **before, clicked, after**

Can someone clarify me this

Comment: `click()` is synchronous. The callback function won't be put in the event loop. You can check this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621545/is-triggering-event-listeners-using-click-asynchronous).