# How long can promise stay unhandled without triggering "unhandledrejection" event?

Tags: javascript, promise, settimeout, event-loop, unhandled-promise-rejection

I am wondering when exactly do browsers check for unhandled promises?
I thought that check is performed in the end of event loop tick. But simple experiment shows the opposite.

If I register two handlers for `unhandledrejection` and `rejectionhandled` events:

```js
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', function(event) {
    console.log('UNHANDLED!'); 
    event.preventDefault();
});

window.addEventListener('rejectionhandled', function(event) {
    console.log('HANDLED!'); 
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

And then run such code:

```js
let promise = Promise.reject(new Error("Promise Failed!"));
// Plan handling in next tick, 
//  in my understanding it SHOULD happen AFTER the unhandledrejection will be triggered
setTimeout(() => promise.catch(err => console.log('CAUGHT!')), 0);
```

I expect events `unhandledrejection` and `rejectionhandled` to be triggered. But they are not triggered (there is no 'UNHANDLED!' and 'HANDLED!' messages in console).

The most strange is that if I change 0 to 1 ms in setTimeout, the events are triggered:

```js
let promise = Promise.reject(new Error("Promise Failed!"));
// Plan handling after 1 ms, 
// REALLY happens AFTER the unhandledrejection is triggered
setTimeout(() => promise.catch(err => console.log('CAUGHT!')), 1);
```

I could not find an explanation in HTML5 spec.

I tried to run provided snippets in several browsers' consoles (Chrome, Firefox, Safari), and expected `unhandledrejection` and `rejectionhandled` events to be triggered. But they did not.

Could someone explain such behaviour, or provide some useful links?

Comment: This *might* have something to do with the fact that `.reject()` wraps the rejection reason value in a *new* Promise instance.

Comment: @Pointy I tried throwing in an async function instead of `Promise.reject` and got the same results. I remember that there was  a slight difference between `setTimeout(0)` and `setTimeout(1)`

Comment: [Specs are here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#notify-about-rejected-promises) the actual check is made in a DOM task, it's up to the UA to set the priority with other tasks scheduled on other task-sources.

Answer (score 2):

To understand the behavior of the code you provided, you should first understand the following concepts:

- Event Loop
- Call Stack
- Callback Queue

This excerpt from [Javascript Runtime: JS Engine, Event Loop, Call Stack, Execution Contexts, Heap, and Queues](https://itnext.io/javascript-runtime-js-engine-event-loop-call-stack-execution-contexts-heap-and-queues-4826d064ad76#:%7E:text=The%20Callback%20Queue%20is%20a,the%20Call%20Stack%20is%20empty.) is helpful to understand the above concepts.

> After an asynchronous event occurs (a timer expires or a network request completes), the associated callback function is placed into the Callback Queue.
> When the Call Stack becomes empty (meaning all synchronous tasks are complete), the Event Loop checks the Callback Queue.
> If there are any callback functions in the Callback Queue, the Event Loop takes the first one and passes it to the Call Stack for execution.

Next, you should understand how JavaScript Timers and `setTimeout` work. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28651001/8993080) should help you understand Timers and `setTimeout`.

> It is the environment that puts these callbacks [from setTimeout] onto the queue, to be executed by the single threaded JavaScript engine.

Now if you understand all that, here is a walkthrough of the code you provided. I have named some of the functions for clarity.

First, we add the event listeners. They will act as you described, but here is a reference for the [Promise rejection events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#promise_rejection_events) `unhandledrejection` and `rejectionhandled`.

> unhandledrejection
> Sent when a promise is rejected but there is no rejection handler available.

> rejectionhandled
> Sent when a handler is attached to a rejected promise that has already caused an unhandledrejection event.

```
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', function unhandledrejectionHandler(event) {
    console.log('UNHANDLED!'); 
    event.preventDefault();
});

window.addEventListener('rejectionhandled', function rejectionhandledHandler(event) {
    console.log('HANDLED!'); 
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Now I will take you through the two cases when the delay is `0` and when the delay is `1`.

```
let promise = Promise.reject(new Error("Promise Failed!"));

let promiseCatchingCb = () => promise.catch(err => console.log('CAUGHT!'))

// Timer executes promiseCatchingCb immediately, adding it to the top of the call stack
setTimeout(promiseCatchingCb, 0);
```

1. Promise rejected
2. `promiseCatchingCb` is immediately added to callback queue and executed
3. window `unhandledrejection` event listener never triggered because rejected promise is already handled

```
let promise = Promise.reject(new Error("Promise Failed!"));

let promiseCatchingCb = () => promise.catch(err => console.log('CAUGHT!'))

// Timer executes promiseCatchingCb immediately, adding it to the top of the call stack
setTimeout(promiseCatchingCb, 1);
```

1. Promise rejected
2. `promiseCatchingCb` is not immediately added to the callback queue because timer is still ongoing (1ms)
3. `unhandledrejection` event is fired and `unhandledrejectionHandler` is added to the callback queue and executed
4. `promiseCatchingCb` is added to the callback queue and executed
5. `rejectionhandled` event is fired and `rejectionhandledHandler` is added to the callback queue and executed

In short, when you set the delay of `setTimeout` to be 0, there isn't any time for the `unhandledrejection` event to be fired. This isn't the same as synchronous code executing on the callstack happening before asynchronous code executing on the callback queue because the different functions in question are all sharing the callback queue.

Comment: This seems to assume that firing events is asynchronous. It's not necessarily. Here the specs ask that the UA queues a task to fire the event but in some cases events are fired synchronously.

Comment: example of a synchronous event: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621545/is-triggering-event-listeners-using-click-synchronous